# What is the highest item level gear you can receive from a BFA world quest?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So far in Battle for Azeroth, the highest base item level I have seen on world quest gear is 330 for solo quests and 340 for dungeons. The highest item level I have received from a world quest is a titanforged 350.

What is the highest item level you can receive from a world quest? Also, will the world quest item levels increase as new content is released?

**Note:** This question was asked during patch 8.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Right now the non-titanforged ilvl cap of WQs is **340** (such as dungeon quests).
2. Titanforged items can go **up to 400** (global TF limit), except for weapons:
3. Weapons can only be **warforged** (+5 or +10 ilvl)

We do not know (yet) if the WQ items will be buffed in the future. Since the titanforged proccs are global we know that at least that limit will increase when new raid tiers will be released.